# Write unit test for Edit function which calls fs writeFile

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, fs

I am writing a functions to read, write and edit a locally stored json file. Have written the functions. Having trouble writing unit test for the Edit function.

I am using Jest to write the test cases. Have got success for read and write functions. But having trouble for the edit function, which takes the exact location where to change the value as parameter and then calls the `writeFile`.

```
function jsonEditor(path, version, prot, index, layer, field, value) {
// Read json
  jsonReader(path).then((response) => {
    const fileData = response;
    fileData[version][prot].connections[index][layer][field] = value;
    //call the WriteFile function
    writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(fileData, null, 2), (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  });
}
```

Not able to understand how to use mock here.

Comment: did you check https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#examples ? that example mocks `fs`'s methods

Comment: @skyboyer it doesn't implement writeFile. Also the function has to handel async operation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
import fs from 'fs';

export const jsonReader = async (path): Promise<any> => {
  return { v1: { a: { connections: [{ someLayer: { someField: 'real value' } }] } } };
};

export function jsonEditor(path, version, prot, index, layer, field, value) {
  // Read json
  return jsonReader(path).then(response => {
    const fileData = response;
    fileData[version][prot].connections[index][layer][field] = value;
    // call the WriteFile function
    fs.writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(fileData, null, 2), err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('write file successfully');
    });
  });
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import * as jsonUtils from './';

describe('jsonUtils', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  describe('#jsonEidtor', () => {
    test('should read json and write file correctly', async () => {
      let callback;
      jest.spyOn(fs, 'writeFile').mockImplementation((path, data, cb) => {
        callback = cb;
      });
      const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
      const mResponse = { v2: { b: { connections: [{ someLayer: { someField: '' } }] } } };
      jest.spyOn(jsonUtils, 'jsonReader').mockResolvedValueOnce(mResponse);
      await jsonUtils.jsonEditor('somePath', 'v2', 'b', 0, 'someLayer', 'someField', 'fake value');
      expect(fs.writeFile).toBeCalledWith(
        'somePath',
        JSON.stringify({ v2: { b: { connections: [{ someLayer: { someField: 'fake value' } }] } } }, null, 2),
        callback
      );
      callback();
      expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('write file successfully');
    });

    test('should throw error when write file error', async () => {
      let callback;
      jest.spyOn(fs, 'writeFile').mockImplementation((path, data, cb) => {
        callback = cb;
      });
      const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
      const mResponse = { v2: { b: { connections: [{ someLayer: { someField: '' } }] } } };
      jest.spyOn(jsonUtils, 'jsonReader').mockResolvedValueOnce(mResponse);
      await jsonUtils.jsonEditor('somePath', 'v2', 'b', 0, 'someLayer', 'someField', 'fake value');
      expect(fs.writeFile).toBeCalledWith(
        'somePath',
        JSON.stringify({ v2: { b: { connections: [{ someLayer: { someField: 'fake value' } }] } } }, null, 2),
        callback
      );
      const err = new Error('write file error');
      expect(() => callback(err)).toThrowError(err);
      expect(logSpy).not.toBeCalled();
    });
  });

  describe('#jsonReader', () => {
    test('should return response', async () => {
      const actualValue = await jsonUtils.jsonReader('somePath');
      expect(actualValue).toEqual({ v1: { a: { connections: [{ someLayer: { someField: 'real value' } }] } } });
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57671298/index.spec.ts (6.941s)
  jsonUtils
    #jsonEidtor
      ✓ should read json and write file correctly (11ms)
      ✓ should throw error when write file error (2ms)
    #jsonReader
      ✓ should return response (2ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    write file successfully

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.178s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57671298